# Not receiving json data with a REST call

Tags: android, json, api, rest, retrofit

I am trying to consume my own REST call using retrofit. My only clue on why it doesn't work is that it says that the type of information is "text/html" even though I am sure it's json. That being said I haven't found any answers that solve my problem.

Payload:

```
  [
    {
        "user_id": "32",
        "username": "Marko",
        "last_activity": "2020-04-26 20:44:00",
        "user_image": "slika2"
    },
    {
        "user_id": "33",
        "username": "dejan",
        "last_activity": "2020-04-26 20:44:00",
        "user_image": "slika3"
    }
]
```

My chat class:

```
public class Chat {

    @SerializedName("user_id")
    private String userId;

    private String username;

    @SerializedName("last_activity")
    private String lastActivity;

    @SerializedName("user_image")
    private String userImage;\

    ...constructor/getters

   }
```

Api Interface:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api_get_all_chats.php")
Call<List<Chat>> getChats(
        @Field("id") String id
);
```

Api client:

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.level(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://MYIP/emob%20projekat/api/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }
```

And the whole request:

```
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(userApi.class);

        Call<List<Chat>> call = apiInterface.getChats(u.getUserInfo().getUserId());

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Chat>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Chat>> call, Response<List<Chat>> response) {
                chatList = new ArrayList<>(response.body());
                chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getApplication().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_view, chatList);
                listView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Chat>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication().getApplicationContext(), "ne valja" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
```

Any type of a clue where I am messing up would be much appreciated.

Comment: try to run the same request in POSTMAN

Comment: I did, and it works perfectly.

Comment: What is the ip? is it localhost or plain IP or public IP?

Answer (score 1):

You base url has space when I decoded it I got

```
http://MYIP/emob projekat/api/
```

i recommend you to put base URL without encoding

Comment: I will update that, but it wont change anything. I already am using one REST call from the same folder and it works without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about `cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"` on your `AndroidManifest`. I see you code is fine and I think maybe the problem about your URL with a `http` scheme.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to specify what response your client expects with `Accept:application/json` either in you API Interface with:

```java
@FormUrlEncoded
@Headers({"Accept:application/json"})
@POST("api_get_all_chats.php")
Call<List<Chat>> getChats(
        @Field("id") String id
);
```

Either in your API client with `new Retrofit.Builder().addHeader("Accept","application/json");`.

This [issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1524) in square/retrofit is very similar to yours (only the inverse, since in the issue it is the server that does not accepts `text/html` while in your case it seems to be your client. Maybe, as in the issue, you are employing [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) as well which cannot parse the `text/html` flavored response)

Answer (score 1):

You need an interceptor like this.

```
public class CustomInterceptor extends Interceptor {

    @override 
    public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) {    
        return chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").addHeader("Accept", "application/json").build())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to log the request, to see exactly what is sent, with headers, url, body and response : https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Secondly, are you sure that you have to make a POST request, a GET seems better ?